# How to import a Particular columns again in mysql table via excel

Tags: mysql, excel

I Have a table in my Mysql like Below:

```
ID  Name Email  PhoneNo
1   Nisan   a@xyz.com  12345
2  Anbu b@xyz.com  123456
3  ram   c@xyz.com  15623
4   rama   d@xyz.com   12356
```

like above 1000 records.

I want to import Name And PhoneNo column again into this same table. So that Name and PhoneNo column only updated. My Data is in excel format

How to do that in php mysql?

Answer (score 0):

what you have to do is use mysql third party tool.

something like SQLyog. Using this software you can import data from csv file or etc..

Comment: Am not using SQLyog. Is it  possible to import prticular columns into table while using SQLyog. ( I have 5000 records in my table)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [EasyXLS](http://www.easyxls.com/net-excel-library) Excel library as third party tool. It can be integrated in PHP. Here is some code sample:

```
// Create an instance of the class that imports Excel files
$workbook = new COM("EasyXLS.ExcelDocument");

// Import Excel file to List
$rows = $workbook ->easy_ReadXLSXSheet_AsList("file.xlsx", "Sheet1", "B2:D5");
```

Import the data to a list than extract the first and the last columns and insert them into MySQL table. If you want the columns separately call the easy_ReadXLSXSheet_AsList method twice.

For more details see this link about [importing Excel to MySQL](https://www.easyxls.com/manual/FAQ/import-excel-to-mysql.html).